# Cant update old Google Play Services lib for a newer version

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, app-update

I have an old app working developed with Eclipse with Google Play Services Lib version 4323000.
The proyect contains the google-play-services_lib and the app proyect itself (inside the app proyect in the libs folder there is the google-play-services_lib.jar file too)

Ok I downloaded from here https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8115000_r27.zip this version to try out the update. I removed the old google-play-services_lib folder and replaced it by the new one.

At first I got that I had a mismatch cause the jar inside the libs app folder was diferent from the one of the google-play_services_lib folder so I replaced it with the updated jar but I got errors.

Android manifest has

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Even when I compile the app and test it, the app launchs and close inmediatelly.

What could be causing the error?? Help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you already changed the version of that in the gradle?

Comment: Im using Eclipse not Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

From `...\google_play_services_8115000_r27.zip\google-play-services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\version.xml`, I found the `google_play_services_version` integer resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">8115000</integer>
</resources>
```

This is also same as in the file name of the zip file that you have.

So, you can finally replace the value like this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="8115000" />
```

Comment: in which part exactly?